# EF code first to MySQL db hosted on Azure Linux VM

Tags: mysql, azure, ef-code-first, centos

I have a MySQL server hosted on CentOS 7 running as a VM in Azure. I have opened the port 3306 on this VM and I am able to connect to this MySQL server to create a database & table from MySQL workbench

Now I am trying to create a code first database using EF6 & C# on this MySQL server using the MySQL.Data.Entity package on nuget. The version of the MySQL.Data dll I get is 6.9.5.0. When I try to run add-migration command I get the error below.

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved for member     'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String   language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean  ignoreChanges)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Type is not resolved for member 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data,     Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
```

This however works fine when I try to connect to a MySQL server on my shared web hosting provider which I have been told runs on a windows server.

Is this a known issue, are we not able to connect to a MySQL database hosted on Linux using EF. I would appreciate any pointers

**UPDATE 1**

I have missed the point that the MySQL connector is not part of the .NET framework & hence not installed in the GAC as mentioned in this post below

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,593463,599082#msg-599082

Obviously the package manager looks into the GAC for known types & it couldnt seem to find MySql.Data. The error went away when doing an add-migration when the MySQL.Data.dll was added to the GAC (\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319) but reappears on update-database.

**UPDATE 2**

Tried to create a database using c# code with MySqlCommand and it seemed to work perfectly from the same project. So it seems that its not working with the code first commands from the package manager & the problem doesnt seem to be with MySQL on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the obvious, it was a schoolboy error. I did not have the attribute

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

on my DbContext class. Its strange that including the verbose flag does not give any hint about the error

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error. I installed the MySQL connector and it worked.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=450594